# c++ serializer with template and polymorphism

Tags: c++, design-patterns

(For simplicity's sake, serializer will be called **write** and deserializer will be called **read**)

I'm writing a C++ game serializer from scratch with no library allowed.

The main concern i have is to keep the read and write in sync (the read values must be the same as the written ones). So the `Packer` handles both tasks and is specified with an enum.

## What i have

```
enum PackerType {
    WRITE,
    READ
}

template <PackerType PType>
class Packer {
    char *buffer; // Packer will write here
    uint32_t index;

    template <typename T>
    void Pack(T & value); // Calls appropriate functions depending on PType
}
```

## What i want to be able to do

```
class ElementToSerialize : ISeriablizable {

    virtual void WriteAndRead(Packer & p) {
        p.Pack(32);
        p.Pack("Hello World");
    }
}

Packer<WRITE> wpacker;
Packer<READ> rpacker;
rpacker.buffer = wpacker.buffer;

WriteAndRead(wpacker); // Will write everything in wpacker.buffer
WriteAndRead(rpacker); // Will read wpacker.buffer
```

So i know this is not possible in C++, but what i'm looking for is an elegant way of dealing with this issue. I'm already aware of type-erasure, but i'm not a fan of the solution.

Comment: one posiible solution: you can change `WriteAndRead` to template.

Comment: I don't necessarily see the need for using templates here, you could just save in a member of the Packer object whether it's a writer or reader and make it act accordingly at runtime.

Comment: @appleapple even though it's not specified in the exemple, this function is supposed to be a virtual one. I'll add it to be clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about starting with something like this:

```
class IPacker
{
public:
   virtual void Pack(int& value) = 0;
   virtual void Pack(float& value) = 0;
}

class ISeriablizable
{
public:
    virtual void Serialize(IPacker & p) = 0;
}

class WritePacker : public IPacker
{
   char* buffer;
   int index = 0;
public:
    WritePacker(char* buffer) : buffer(buffer) {}
    void Pack(int& value) override { /* write to buffer */ }
    void Pack(float& value) override { /* write to buffer */ }
}

class ReadPacker : public IPacker
{
   char* buffer;
   int index = 0;
public:
    ReadPacker(char* buffer) : buffer(buffer) {}
    void Pack(int& value) override { /* read from buffer */ }
    void Pack(float& value) override { /* read from buffer */ }
}

class ElementToSerialize : public ISeriablizable
{
     int x = 32;
     std::string y = "Hello world";

     void Serialize(IPacker & p) override
     {
         p.Pack(x);
         p.Pack(y);
     }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to keep the templates to garanty full support of all types, but it seems i'll have to limit myself. I'll go with that, thanks !

Comment: To IPacker you could add method: virtual Pack(void* data, size_t size) = 0;   Then add   template<T> void Pack(T& value) { Pack(&value, sizeof(value));

Comment: But... that only works if T is a plain data type. If it's a std::string or some other type containing a pointer to other data, it's not going to work.

Comment: Indeed, i could specify some `Pack(std::string)` and such, but i don't think the `void*` solution is needed for this solution. Interesting idea nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a requirement, you could avoid using templates altogether, and just store whether the Packer is `read` or `write` so you know it at runtime (example):

```
class Packer {
public:
    enum Type {
        READ,
        WRITE
    };

    char *buffer; // Packer will write here
    uint32_t index;
    Type type;

    Packer(Type t) : type(t) {}

    void Pack(int& value);
    void Pack(float& value);
    void Pack(std::string& value);
    // etc...
};
```

Comment: This is the model i'm currently using, but it doesn't really feel OO-ish. I'm essentialy looking for an elegant way of doing it without having to do `if (type == WRITE)`